# How do I make the Google Chrome flag "--allow-file-access-from-files" permanent?

Tags: google-chrome

If you want to allow a local file to access a local file in google chrome you go to the terminal and run

```
$ google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigate to the desktop launcher / menu entry, open the launcher properties dialog for google chrome.

It should look like this:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome %U
```

To make the flags that you want permanent, modify it to something like:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

You may also need to delete and re-pin your icon launchers after modifying it. Chrome should launch with the specified flags enabled after the modification.

Alternatively, you can simply create a new launcher with the above and use it to start chrome.

To check if the flags that you modified are being loaded:

```
$ cat ~/.config/google-chrome/Local\ State
```

and scroll up to the block entitled

`"session_restore"`

Your flags should be listed in the block, before

`--flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end`.

Opening chrome and navigating to the URL

```
chrome://version/
```

should also list enabled flags in the

```
Command Line
```

block

This is a list of the google-chrome / chromium flags:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: @Sam, you should remove `How can I make that option always be turned on when ever google chrome is executed beyond running a .desktop every time` part from your question as it will create confusion.

Comment: @Web-E Okay sounds good.

Comment: Install `menulibre` as a way to get to the "launcher".

Answer (score 3):

The different modes like `--allow-file-access-from-files` are flags/switches and not meant for general users. So you can't change them permanently with regular builds. The purpose of these switches/argument is to provide choice. These flags are neither supported nor recommended and must be used as temporary.

Since you don't want to use `.desktop` file or changing any shortcut. The only thing you can do is to look into code of open source `chromium`.

Customize the code and build it. Then only it will open with your desired mode.

<sub>[List of switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files) | [Source](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)</sub>

Comment: That is what I feared. I'll just use the .desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Google-chrome and Chromium should function the same, the differences are pretty minor except for multimedia (especially Flash) and some file/folder locations (chromium instead of google-chrome) see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome

You should check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium_Tips_and_Tweaks
especially:

```
Making it all persistent

You can export your flags from ~/.profile:
export CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS="--disk-cache-dir=/tmp --disk-cache-size=50000000"

Or add them to /etc/chromium/default:
# Default settings for chromium. This file is sourced by /usr/bin/chromium
#
# Options to pass to chromium
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--scroll-pixels=200"

Chromium will prefer the user defined flags in CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS to those defined in
/etc/chromium/default.
```

Comment: This is the only thing that's worked for me so far - adding `CHROME_USER_FLAGS=` to `/etc/skel/.bashrc` when the laptop is built